# Is it normal that my cat licks my clothes?

Tags: cats, socializing

My cat likes (specially in the mornings) to lie in my chest while I'm reading or looking something in my laptop and then he starts to purr and to lick my clothes. He does it with as much passion as when he eats his favourite food.

He does this very often and I don't understand why. He's the first pet I have and I have him just from very recently. Is this a normal behaviour of the cat?

I don't know if he used to do this with his previous owners or if it is normal. Why does he act this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's normal -- or as normal as cats ever get; they're quirky beasts.

Petting a cat is grooming behavior; he's grooming you in return. It's a friendly gesture... and/or a hint that he wants attention. Probably both.

I've known cats which lick elbows, lick fingertips, chew gently on fingertips, or just groom whatever's within reach... one woud try to lick your lips if you blew gently at her. Not all cats do this, or do it to all humans, but it's far from uncommon.

Comment: And if you're wondering why your cat would be grooming you, that's because between adults it's a bonding activity. In other words, it's a sign of affection, intended to be relaxing for both of you.

Comment: Good point, @mhwombat; edited. My two cats will often settle in for a session of mutual grooming before curling up together for a nap.

Answer (score -1):

My cat does the exact same thing. In the morning he would start licking, purring and kneading me. It’s a sign of love and he wants to cuddle you. Don’t worry

Comment: Welcome to Pets SE, Alina. :) Can you give us a link to some online references about cat behavior? Or perhaps give us more information about your personal experience with cats? (thanks)

Comment: Welcome to Pets :) Thanks for your input. You may wish to expand the answer as @elbrant says. Check out [answer] for some more tips.